# How can I catch google picker errors?

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client, google-picker

I request the oauth2 authorization in a previous step, so I have the access_token.

I use the token to display a google picker. Everything works but when the user manually revokes my app access from `Apps with access to your account` the `picker` object shows the sign in button.

**Is it possible to catch this error so I can hide the picker and ask user for re-authorization using my own logic instead of using `gapi.load('auth')`?**

```
function onApiLoad() {
            gapi.load('picker', onPickerApiLoad);
        }


        function onPickerApiLoad() {
            var authBtn = document.getElementById('auth');
            authBtn.disabled = false;
            authBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                pickerApiLoaded = true;
                createPicker();
            });

        }

        function createPicker() {
            if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
                var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView().
                setIncludeFolders(true).
                setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
                var picker = new google.
                picker.PickerBuilder().
                addView(docsView).
                setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
                setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
                setCallback(pickerCallback).
                build();
                picker.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```